# How to store data in ORACLE table column of type SYS.URITYPE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to store data in a column of Oracle table which is of URITYPE using JDBC. I learned that to supply data to SYS.URITYPE from java, we need to use java.net.URL. I tried exactly same

```
pstmt.setURL(4, new java.net.URL("http://google.com"));
```

but still i keep on getting this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SYS.URITYPE got CHAR.
```

I cant find useful information related to this. I will appreaciate if someone can share infomation on finxing this issue.

Thanks, 
Suvojit

Comment: Try `insert into table (uricolumn) values (HTTPURIType('http://www.oracle.com'))` where actual URL is query parameter

Comment: @Egor: Yes that works. Thank you so much my friend. My problem is solved but I will appreciate if you can share some useful links which can enhance my knowledge on this subject.

Comment: You can try [Link1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb15dbu.htm#BABBACBF) and [Link2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml35.htm). For detail description on Database URI Types [Check This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_dburi.htm).